# Can completely remove black paint from Bowser?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

I see many videos about Black Bowser's battle from Paper Mario: Color Splash. But, after black paint removed from Bowser's head, the black paint takes control of him again and the second phase started.

However, can completely remove black paint from Bowser? If yes, how and what happens after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the black paint in the first phase, the black paint can't be lower than half of bowser.